# Is this possible to use fake AP to get wpa keys?

Tags: wifi, wpa2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to speed up WPA/WPA2-PSK cracking using a rogue AP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-wpa-wpa2-psk-cracking-using-a-rogue-ap)

Is it possible to get the WPA preshared key with a fake AP with the same SSID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not ;-)

[Is it possible to speed up WPA/WPA2-PSK cracking using a rogue AP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-wpa-wpa2-psk-cracking-using-a-rogue-ap)

WPA/WPA2-PSK uses a PTK (Pairwise Transient Key) for each client to encrypt the communication !