# evil twin like attack

Tags: wifi, evil-twin, rogue-ap

Is it possible to make a fake AP with the same SSID that has a password and when clients try to access it and type a password, the software verifies it with a handshake?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Is it possible to speed up WPA/WPA2-PSK cracking using a rogue AP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-wpa-wpa2-psk-cracking-using-a-rogue-ap). That didn't come up on my search for the answer to your question, but duplicates of it did.

Comment: It is not fully clear what you are asking. But possible duplicate of [How does WPA2-PSK prevent evil twin password phishing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110927) or [can wpa2 wifi be hacked by capturing data on an evil twin?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79343/).